# webform custom url - open in new window

Tags: webforms

I successfully managed to create a custom URL made of a fixed part, and a user submitted value, such as http://somepage.com/userinput.
After submitting, this URL is opened in the same window; I need to open it in new window.

Is it possible to achieve this using template override, or any other way?

Comment: Does that page contain a form generated with the form API?

Comment: I think so, I used webform module. I created 2 fields. First is a textfield and second hidden field with url

Comment: anybody has any ideas?